# Data frame matrix indexing without type coercion

Tags: r

I am trying to replace values fitting a condition (less than zero) in one `data.frame` with values from another:

```
> df
  id val1 val2 val3
1  a    1    0   -1
2  b   -1   NA    2

> replacevals
  id val1 val2 val3
1  a    1    3    0
2  b    2   NA    3
```

Desired output:

```
  id val1 val2 val3
1  a    1    0    0
2  b    2   NA    2
```

I know that the two data frames are structured identically. I am able to make the desired replacement like this...

```
negs <- !is.na( df ) & df < 0  # logical matrix
df[negs] <- replacevals[negs]
```

...but now the column classes have changed:

```
> sapply(df, class)
         id        val1        val2        val3 
"character" "character"   "numeric" "character"
```

In this case, they can be converted back to the correct values by mapping the classes from the replacement data onto the final data:

```
df[] <- Map(`class<-`, df, sapply(replacevals, class))
```

I am working with some large datasets, however, and would prefer to avoid the time it takes to do the type coercions. The official R documentation recommends avoiding this, but I cannot see another way that is as simple.

> Matrix indexing (x[i] with a logical or a 2-column integer matrix i) using [ is not recommended. For extraction, x is first coerced to a matrix. For replacement, logical matrix indices must be of the same dimension as x. Replacements are done one column at a time, with multiple type coercions possibly taking place.

Is there a better way to do this?

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(id = c('a','b'), val1 = c(1,-1), val2 = c(0,NA),
                 val3 = c(-1,2), stringsAsFactors = F)
replacevals <- data.frame(id = c('a','b'), val1 = c(1,2), val2 = c(3,NA), 
                          val3 = c(0,3), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to create the condition only on the numeric columns

```
j1 <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
negs <- !is.na( df[j1] ) & df[j1] < 0  # logical matrix
df[j1][negs] <- replacevals[j1][negs]

df
#  id val1 val2 val3
#1  a    1    0    0
#2  b    2   NA    2

str(df)
#'data.frame':  2 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ id  : chr  "a" "b"
# $ val1: num  1 2
# $ val2: num  0 NA
# $ val3: num  0 2
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely answers the question as posed. Do you have any ideas though for if the condition were not just on the numeric columns? For example, if I wanted to replace `NA`s (of all types) in the same way, but with mixed numeric and character columns?

Comment: @C.Braun  In that case, apply on each column separately with `Map` i.e. `df[] <- Map(fn, df, replacevals)`.  Create the `fn` that should be making sense for each type i.e. `fn <- function(x, y) replace(x, is.na(x), 0)`